# Temporary files when using xUnit

Tags: xunit.net

Does xUnit have a folder where I can create temporary files during my test case (like MSTEST) or should I use something like `Path.GetTempFileName()` instead?

Comment: Maybe [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions) can also help here?

Comment: System.IO.Abstractions seems like a good library to have around but in my case I actually need to create a file. My problem is where should I create it. I was hoping for a folder location contextually bound to each use case that would be cleaned up after the test run.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: No @SebastianWeber I did not find anything "out-of-the-box" for this. But you could implement your own solution similar to what is described by http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2013/12/28/154992.aspx. A disposable type that manage a temporary directory which is destroyed on disposal.